# How to get the information of a thread about NUMA

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, memory, numa

My server is a NUMA architecture machine, the system is Ubuntu.

I'm programming a multi-threading project witch C++11.

Now I want to get some information about the threads in my project to get its performance.

I've known that `/proc/<pid>/task/<tid>/status` contains some information but it is not enough for me.

For example, I want to know the access number on all of NUMAs of a thread, something as below:

```
thread id: 32456
access Numa0 mem: 200 times
access Numa1 mem: 500 times
```

Are there some tools to some methods to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Intel VTune Amplifier](https://software.intel.com/en-us/vtune). You can profile your program and get statistics about memory accesses per NUMA node. See the features page for [memory storage](https://software.intel.com/en-us/vtune/features/memory-storage).